# Storing multiple un-formatted user inputs in list

Tags: python, list

The user inputs the following:

```
3
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Where each line is a *separate* input, so the input would have to be read in line by line.

(ex. read '3', then read '1,2...etc.).

How would you then transform the data to be shown in a list like so?:

```
list1 = [
        [3],
        [1,2],
        [1,2,3],
        [1,2,3,4],
        [1,2,3,4,5]
]
```

What I have so far:

```
def format(): 
    user_input = [] 
    uInput = input() 
    uInput = uInput.replace(" ", "") # Get rid of the spaces in the input
    user_input.append(uInput) # Append values to list
    return user_input
```

But this is problematic, as the turn value is returned as a string and I would have to call the function X times to get all the input (row) values.

Answer (score 0):

You can break a line of numbers into a list of numbers like:

#### Code:

```
def split_ints_to_list(data):
    return [int(x) for x in data.split()]
```

You can then convert multiple of those, to a list of lists like:

```
list_of_lists = [split_ints_to_list(line) for line in input_data]
```

Both of these use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a list.

#### Test Code:

```
input_data = [x.strip() for x in """
    3
    1 2
    1 2 3
    1 2 3 4
    1 2 3 4 5
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
print(input_data)

for line in input_data:
    print(split_ints_to_list(line))

list_of_lists = [split_ints_to_list(line) for line in input_data]
print(list_of_lists)
```

#### Results:

```
['3', '1 2', '1 2 3', '1 2 3 4', '1 2 3 4 5']

[3]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[[3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```